# Calculate the limit of the derivative of an exponential function

Tags: python, decimal, exponential

I am trying to write a program to calculate the limit of the derivative of an exponential function. I have gotten the program to work using the datatype float. But its precision is a bit low. I have tried to use the decimal datatype but can't get it to work with `math.exp` can I get around it? Just trying to get the basic calculating done and the put it into my program.

```
import decimal
import math

a = decimal.Decimal('2.0')
h = decimal.Decimal('0.1')

d=decimal.Decimal((a*(math.exp(a*(a+h))-(math.exp(a*(a)))))/h)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the decimal library's exponential functions.  Search for "exp(" in this page:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

You should also set your precision.

Comment: Thx a bunch that helped